# Eclipse 2021-12(4.22.0) doesn't show "Hide Read-Only Reference" on Search

Tags: eclipse

[image]

I found the Eclipse Version 2021-12 doesn't show the "Hide Read-Only References" on search. In comparison, the older version 2019-06 does have this feature.

Question> Does this version support this feature?

Comment: On what kind of search?

Comment: C++ Reference search